# Laravel Modal login produces MethodNotAllowedHttpException but does authenticate

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, modal-dialog

I'm displaying a form where, if the user is not authenticated, there's a button that will launch a modal login form.

I enter valid credentials and experience a MethodNotAllowedHttpException.  However, I am authenticated.  In another tab (or by hitting back and reloading)

```
    (1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException
    in RouteCollection.php (line 251)
    at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST'))
    in RouteCollection.php (line 238)
```

My modal form:

```
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label  for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email"
                               value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>
                        @if ($errors->has('email'))
                            <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong></span>
                        @endif
                    </div></div>
                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>
                        @if ($errors->has('password'))
                            <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong></span>
                        @endif
                    </div></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label> <input type="checkbox"
                                       name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me</label></div></div></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                        <a href="#reset_modal" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#reset_modal">
                            Forgot Your Password?</a></div></div></form>
```

Relevant portion of my SessionController.php:

```
public function store (Request $request) {
    if (! auth()->attempt(request(['email', 'password']))) {
        return back();
    }
    return redirect('/dashboard');
}
```

Relevant route:

```
Route::post('/login', 'SessionController@store');
```

I cannot seem to narrow down the cause to the exception.  Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you logging in through the SessionController as opposed to the Auth\LoginController? Are you using a different package for user authentication?

Comment: change your controller once

Comment: Run `php artisan route:list` to see what the router has listed for the /login route.

Comment: Yes, `php artisan route:list` shows both the GET and POST for /login

Comment: @RaushanKumar you're right.  I'm using the default package.  I must have changed it a while back.  I just changed my routes to Auth\LoginController.  I still get the exception with my modal login while still getting logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a case of an issue due to feedback attempting to post back to the page (originated with a post form) via back which is a GET string.  So the route error was due to that.

I wish there was a way to redirect back using POST.